# c++ Vector optimizations

Tags: c++, vector, stdvector

i have vector, like this:

```
struct cords {
    double x, y;
};
struct road {
    cords start, end;
};
vector<road> roads;
```

And i found a function in my class, that works terribly slow. The main proper of the function is to get all the pairs from vector and to do some math with them. I'm not changing the values of vector's items inside, just reading them pretty often.
First problem i've noticed, that loop itself wasn't fast enough, that's why i'm using:

```
unsigned maxI = roads.size();
unsigned maxJ = roads.size();
for (unsigned i = 0; i < maxI; i++) {
    for (unsigned j = i + 1; j < maxJ; j++) {
        ...
    }
}
```

It gave a resonable time improvement to this function, but not enough.

As i told earlier, stuff inside is just math and few conditions, with calls to vector like that: `roads[j].end.y`.

Next step, i've notice, that if i'm doing

```
for (unsigned i = 0; i < maxI; i++) {
    cords point1 = roads[i].start;
    cords point2 = roads[i].end;
    for (unsigned j = i + 1; j < maxJ; j++) {
```

and using `point1, point2` instead of `roads[j].end.y` it works almost twice faster.

I just don't getting why is it happening and how can i improve it more.

UPD: Not sure, but it might be a compiler-depended question, so i'm using vs2015 with a built-in one.

Comment: You are taking copy

Comment: @arynaq you mean cords? yes, because i want to make it work faster.

Comment: What you show us doesn't make much sense. What is the inner loop for? What are you doing? How do you measure performance? If the performance really bad enough for you to worry (good enough often *is* good enough)? Is the (little) code you show really a major bottleneck in your program? Please [read about how to ask good questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), and try to create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) to show us.

Comment: Impossible to answer. We really need to see what is faster than what. The contents of the inner loop are crucial. The `j=i+1` is intriguing.

Comment: Do you Need to modify point1 and point2 in the inner loop? If not, why are you making copies and not just taking a const reference of them to improve speed?

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude rewrited the question, hope it looks better for you now. thanks for the advice

Comment: @milbrandt i've forgot about const, thanks

Comment: @HeathRaftery `j=i+1`, you know more accurate way to get C(n 2) combination?

Comment: @CrazyWu and take references `const coords &point1 = ...` instead of copying

Comment: @milbrandt that's a great speed improvement, thanks. testing if it will enough

Comment: Ah ha! You're iterating through all the nCr combinations with n=roads.size() and r=2. Makes sense now, and useful information for your question. In that case, the looping method is fine.

Comment: @milbrandt yeah, improved to about 2minutes instead of 2-3hrs (i wasn't waiting that long, approximating)

Comment: @milbrandt i guess, you answer is the most correct for this question, so feel free to post it like a full answer.

Comment: Are you running a debug build? If so, switch to release. In order to make Debug builds easier to debug, they are often orders of magnitude slower than the optimized release build.

Comment: @user4581301 was testing with debug, but you interested, release version takes about 2.5 for the same data. Sounds fine for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If there is no need to temporary modify the `point1`and `point2`in the inner loop, then avoid to copy them just take const reference of them to improve speed.

```
const cords &point1 = roads[i].start;
const cords &point2 = roads[i].end;
```